# jquery not sending hidden input values to the backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my code, I am trying to send the hidden input values to the backend via jquery, but input values is not sending, I don't know why, because it looks ok for me, also the php `$_POST` vars is with same name as input names.

I need to send the *value* of the *hidden input* and get on the backend with the *input name*.

```html
<form id="user_page_form" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities($db_user); ?>" name="user_page" />
  <button id="btn_follow" class="btn btn-outline-success" style="border-radius:8px;">
    <input type="hidden" value="unfollow" name="follow_button" /><i class="fa fa-user"></i>following<i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
    </form>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn_follow').click(function() {
var follow_and_unfollow = $("#user_page_form").serialize();
                     $.post(                            "backend/ajax/follow_and_unfollow.php",
                            follow_and_unfollow
                     ).done(function(data) {   
        $("#result").html(data);
           }).fail(function () {
})     
}
});
</script>     
    <div id="result"></div>
```

I am trying to send the hidden input values   `value="unfollow"` and others , it should work since the php var is with same name of the inputs. my php backend variables:

```
$userpage = $_POST['user_page'];
$follow = $_POST['follow_button'];
```

Comment: Is the form inside a modal, or dynamically generated?

Comment: it's inside a `<section>`

Comment: the button is  dynamically generated, because it will have the `value="unfollow"` or `value="follow"` only the value change, but the button name stay the same

Comment: You have an input inside a button...that's not valid

Comment: I added to outside but it stay the same , still not sending data

Comment: You should be running like `formElement.submit(function(e){ /* AJAX here */ e.preventDefault(); })`. Page is submitting, and the input in the button issue.

Comment: I tried with `e.preventDefault();`  before ask here, but it did't worked

Comment: is there an error in your console? cause I think you've got a missing `)` it should be `})  })  })` at the end..

Comment: I found the problem , my backend was with a invalid variable name

Answer (score 0):

You need to close ur  tab before the for input. 
Or move the input before the button.

```
<form id="user_page_form" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities($db_user); ?>"name="user_page"/>
 <input type="hidden" value="unfollow" name="follow_button" />
 <button id="btn_follow" class="btn btn-outline-success" style="border-radius:8px;">
 <i class="fa fa-user"></i>following<i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
 </form>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn_follow').click(function() {
      var follow_and_unfollow = $("#user_page_form").serialize();
                 $.post("backend/ajax/follow_and_unfollow.php",
                        follow_and_unfollow
                 ).done(function(data) {   
                $("#result").html(data);
                         }).fail(function () {
          })        
         }
       });
 </script>      
<div id="result"></div>
```